# R2HTML or knitr for dynamic report generation?

Tags: r, knitr

I want to write an R function which processes some data and then automatically outputs an html report. This report should contain some fixed text, some text changing according to the underlying data and some figures.

What is the best way to go?
R2HTML or knitr?
What are the advantages of one over the other?

As far as I understood R2HTML allows me to build the html file sequentially while knitr already operates on an predefined .Rhtml file.
So, either use R2HTML or stitch and spin from knitr for on the fly report generation.

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

knitr, every time. Handles graphics, lets you write your report with markdown instead of having to write html everywhere (if you want), caches things, makes coffee for you etc.

Answer (score 5):

I grab this nice opportunity to promote [pander](https://github.com/rapporter/pander) a bit :)

---

This package was written for similar reasons like @Yihui's great `knitr`, although *I wanted to let users really concentrate on the text and R code* without dealing with chunk options etc. So letting users generate pretty `HTML`, `pdf` or even `docx` or `odt` output *automatically* with some predefined options.

These [options](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#pander-options) affects e.g. the [cache engine](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#caching) (handling dependencies *without* any chunk options) or the default [plot options](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/graphs.html) (let it be a "base" R `graphics`, `lattice` or `ggplot2`), so that you do no thave to set the color palette or the minor grid in each of your plots, just once - or live with the package defaults :)

The package captures the results (besides errors/warnings and other messages *and* the output) of all run R expression and can convert to [Pandoc's markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) automatically. There are some helper functions that let you convert the resulting document written in a [brew-like syntax](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#brew-to-pandoc) automatically to e.g. HTML if you have `pandoc` installed, or export R objects to markdown/HTML/any other supported format in a live R session with a [reference class](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#live-report-generation).

**Short demo:**

- [brew file](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/inst/examples/short-code-long-report.brew)
- `Pandoc.brew('file_name.brew', output = 'foo.html', convert = 'html')`
- [HTML output](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/short-code-long-report.html)

Comment: I had run theh demo in 5-6 minutes, including installation of pander and Pandoc. Very impressive! Certainly "knitr et al" can make nice stuff in html or pdf, but fact is that quite many of us need to interact with people using Word. I will indeed promote this package in my workplace.

Comment: Thank you @DagHjermann, it's always great to hear such great feedback :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also build an HTML file sequentially as long as you have a decent text editor like Emacs/ESS or RStudio, etc. `R2HTML` is excellent in terms of its wide support to many R objects (see `methods(HTML)`), but I'll probably frown on `RweaveHTML()` due to its root `Sweave()`.

That said, I think it may be a good idea to combine `R2HTML` and `knitr`, e.g.

````
# A LOESS Example

```{r loess-demo, results='asis'}
cars.lo <- loess(dist ~ speed, cars)
library(R2HTML)
HTML(cars.lo, file = '')
```
````

I was using the R Markdown syntax in the above example. The key is `results='asis'` which means to writing raw HTML code into the output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can also use Sweave to create HTML files, though I have heard that knitr is easier to use.